# Nvidia cosumer grade GPU for computing

Tags: matlab, cuda, nvidia

I have GTX 670 with core i5 3.2GHz dual core with HT and want to use GPU for computing application development. I have lots of computing code in MATLAB and as i found out that it supports CUDA based processing. So, i was thinking to use NVidia dev tools to directly code for CUDA and maximize performance. Right now, Im very tight on budget and on that workstation GPU's cost like hell, so wanted to use existing CUDA so that I can free up my CPU.

So, can i use nvidia consumer grade GPU for computing development? is it possible?

Thanks for answers.

Ashutosh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the GTX 670 specifically listed as "[CUDA-Enabled](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus)".

Comment: But, can i directly use this GPU for CUDA programming and computing application development instead of using MATLAB?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use the CUDA SDK (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) as if it would a super-expensive professional Tesla GPU.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, MATLAB (with Parallel Computing Toolbox) can use many different CUDA cards. See http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/availability/index.html?refresh=true#DM and https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus.

If you want to see how well a variety of different GPUs perform in MATLAB, see: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34080-gpubench